# Visual Studio Code, find javascript definition in html script-tag

Tags: javascript, web, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a web project in Visual Studio Code with HTML, JavaScript and CSS files (nothing special).

Some JavaScript files are defined in a `<script>` tag in an HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myvar01 = true;
  var myvar02 = false;
  var myvar03 = "var99";
</script>
```

The variable `myvar01` is used in a JavaScript file. If I highlight this variable in the JS file and call "Go to Definition" (VSC context menu), the definition in the HTML file is not found. Why? Both files are open in the editor.

Comment: What extensions do you use in Visual Studio Code? I sometimes had issues with some plugins not finding variable references across HTML and JS files.

Comment: ESLint and Live Server